# crash message: you can reopen the window to continue where you left off

Tags: crash, visual-studio-code

I can't open VSCode. It keeps giving me this message and exits.
It's like it's trying to restore the last session but the files might no longer be there.

I have tried installing the latest version but still getting this.
[image: Visual Studio Code. The window has crashed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. The solution that worked for me is the following.

- Close all instances of vscode
- navigate to %appdata%
- Rename Vscode to Vscode.old or some other name
- If you have "Visual Studio Code" rename that folder
- If you have "Code - Insiders" rename that folder
- The general idea is to rename vscode's folder to something else
- Reopen vscode in admin mode

  Hope the solution helps someone

Comment: it does work and may i know why should we rename the app data folder?

Comment: how about for macOS ? today i always happen this issue always crash after reopen . device macbook pro m1 .

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and deleted related files folders then reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Open Explorer and visit the location where VS Code is installed.

In my case

C:\Users\Sameer\AppData\Local\Programs\

Just Delete "**Microsoft VS Code**" Folder.

It will not delete your extension and other settings of your VS Code.

After deleting it, Download and Install  new "**VS Code**"

**BOOM!!..** You're done and error just got vanished.